# Security concern to declare global constants in single .js file

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables, constants, global

Is it a good idea regarding security and maintainability to put all the `const` variables in one single js file, which I can use from all my pages?
Something like this

```
my-constants.js
```

> >

```
const SOME_VAR = "asd";
const SOME_URL = "www.com"
const ASD = "dsa;
```

Comment: It is common to have this sort of a file i.e. config.js etc etc. Obviously don't store any credentials in this file

Comment: Security doesn't have anything to do with putting variables in a file. It's all about what data you assign to those variables, and who can access the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can help maintainability.  If you need to change the global variable in some point in the future you would only need to change it in one spot instead of trying to find every place it is used.  If security is a concern, don't put confidential information in client-side JavaScript.  Anyone with a browser can read it.